# How can I save the order of a table's rows using jquery sortable without using ".toArray()" or ".serialize()"?

Tags: jquery, traversal, jquery-ui-sortable, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

Let's say I have a table that uses jquery sortable. How can I get a row's innerHTML to exchange with another row's innerHTML when dragged and then save the order on submit without using ".toArray()" or ".serialize()". For example, I managed to save the order without using ".toArray()" or ".serialize()" by using the up and down buttons to exhange innerHTML.

```
    jQuery(function() {
    var ids = [];
    $("tbody#sortable").sortable({
        axis: "y",
        items: ".row_order", 
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        placeholder: "must-have-class",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      //Empty the array to avoid duplication.
      ids = [];
      //Store the ids in the array.
      $.each(event.target.children, function() {
            ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
      });
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      //Store the html in local variables
      var prevHtml = ui.item.prev().html();
      var nextHtml = ui.item.next().html();

      //Call .html and pass the html content as an argument
      ui.item.prev().html(nextHtml);
      ui.item.next().html(prevHtml);

      //On an update, loop through the sortable items and reset their items.
      for (var i = 0; i < event.target.children.length; i++) {
        $(event.target.children[i]).attr('id', ids[i]);
      }
    }        
    });
});
```

This is the [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/patrickbateman/r3y75b7o/47/)

Answer (score 2):

Your example won't work because you're assigning the html content of the items to variables and you're not manipulating the DOM elements in any way.

In order to update the inner html, you'd have to call `.html()` on each element and pass the html as an argument:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var ids = [];
  jQuery("#sortable_available").sortable({
    items: "li",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      //Empty the array to avoid duplication.
      ids = [];
      //Store the ids in the array.
      $.each(event.target.children, function() {
        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
      })
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      //Store the html in local variables
      var prevHtml = ui.item.prev().html();
      var nextHtml = ui.item.next().html();

      //Call .html and pass the html content as an argument
      ui.item.prev().html(nextHtml);
      ui.item.next().html(prevHtml);

      //On an update, loop through the sortable items and reset their items.
      for (var i = 0; i < event.target.children.length; i++) {
        $(event.target.children[i]).attr('id', ids[i]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

There might be a better way to maintain the ids, but the above is a rough example of how your requirements can be achieved.

Click **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/u4ucd799/)** for a live demo.

Comment: That would require more complex funtionality i e. Subscribing to the start event and storing ids in variables.

Comment: Yeah. Or you could make the inner content sortable. I'll try and update with an example in a bit.

Comment: It was an example I had saved previously.

Comment: It's no problem. I've updated the fiddle to maintain the ids. I hope the change answers your latest question. If you have further, more specific questions, it's probably best to ask new ones.

Comment: How are you saving the order? Is the order based on the item index, which you can obtain using `.index()` (jquery)?

Comment: I don't see why the update wouldn't be working. Do you have a fiddle I can look at? I want to see how you're forming the data that is passed to your database.

Comment: I don't see anything about the saving aspect (unless I'm missing something obvious)?

Comment: I updated the fiddle it now has the submit function as well as an example of the backend